# Issue with MATCH and TIME formulas for Excel

Tags: excel, time, match

Some values, such as when the MATCH formula is trying to match '0 hr 1 min 00 s' '0 hr 2 min 30 s' and'0 hr 5 min 30 s' produces and N/A message. I have used the EXACT formula to check if the cell values are truly equal in the data sheet, and they are.

I am using the INDEX MATCH MATCH formula in conjunction with the TIME formula.

**The rest of the time intervals that I am using works.** (means that if i select '0 hr 4 min 00 s' it works)

I've screenshotted the steps that are shown through the Evaluate Formula function.

***Why doesn't these specific timings work, but the rest do? Please help, it is so strange.***

```
=INDEX('Rough Breakdown By Percentages'!$C$2:$V$243,MATCH(D6,'Rough Breakdown By Percentages'!$C$2:$C$243,0),MATCH('Rough Breakdown By Percentages'!$M$2,'Rough Breakdown By Percentages'!$C$2:$V$2,0))
```

**The initial formula**
[image: The initial formula]

**Step 1 of evaluation shows no issues with the time interval**
[image: Step 1 of evaluation shows no issues with the time interval]

**Step 2 shows N/A for the Match function**
[image: Step 2 shows N/A for the Match function]

Comment: Most likely rounding off issues. Time in excel is based on days. 1 is equivalent to 1 day. 1/24 is equivalent to 1 hour, etc. When you get to smaller values, the numbers become very small and don't often have a limit of decimal numbers, but excel is forced to use a limited number of decimals for the match. There's likely a discrepancy there somewhere. You would probably be better off using index/match on the text version of the time, then excel won't use the numeric version of the time your are looking up.

Comment: I thought that it might be the case to! I tried using the round function and it produced more errors. But it is strange though, I am pretty sure the other time intervals will have rounding errors as well, but they didnt. Anyways, can you elaborate on the text version of the time and how I should convert the current data that I have to that?

Comment: It would be nice if you simplified your formulas before posting it, e.g. `'Rough Breakdown By Percentages'!$C$2:$V$243` is much less readable than `$C$2:$V$243` and does not add any clue on solving the problem.

Comment: Rounding may be an issue but I think it's more probable that you see only time values because of cell formatting and the day differs in the cells, e.g. 2013-04-05 12:34:56 is not the same as today 12:34:56. I suggest to compare the value you want to find (first parameter of `MATCH`, let's call it B1) with the value where you want to find it (e.g. if you search in C1:V243 and know that it is the third cell, then C3). Put a formula into A1: `=B1=C3`

Comment: Sorry about the complicated formula! And thank you so much for your suggestion, I will pay attention to that next time. As for your suggestion, do u mean that I should compare the 2 cells that I am attempting to match? I've used the 'EXACT' function to compare the 2 cells and it gives me a 'TRUE'.

Comment: If you are referring to putting C3 = B1 directly into the formula, I can't do that because i intend on adding 30 seconds with the TIME function to one of the data validation cells created. This way the index match match will generate a different value based on the data selected in the data validation list (for the screenshots it is one of the yellow cells "00hrs 6 mins 0sec")

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You'll need to use helper a column if you intend to keep the original values from C2:V243 for later calculations. If not, then you can replace the original range with the calculated one. To calculate the text version of the times, you can use something like `=TEXT(C2,"hh:mm:ss")` in an adjacent column and when you perform the lookup, you would use something like `... MATCH(TEXT(D6,"hh:mm:ss"), ...` (and replace the ranges C2:V243 with the new ranges you 'textified')

Answer (score 0):

Yup so I did further research with the kind help of the individuals who answered here and it is simply because of the rounding error. So i took the original time data and rounded it to 15 decimal places and it worked! THANK YOU EVERYONE for your help!